# Hide/ unhide text fields based on user type using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the form page is loaded, it automatically pulls the type of user account from the DB into a text field called, check_type. I want to hide/ unhide a text field based on user account type. If it is an Admin account then show textfield1, and for any other account, type hide textfield1.

Here is the code I wrote; but, it is not working. Maybe, I have used incorrect syntax.

```
 <?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user' ";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$type = $row['acct_type'];


}
                    
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Hide/ Unhide</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var check_type = document.getElementById("check_type");
    var atype = document.getElementById("atype");

    if(check_type == 'Admin')
    {
        atype.style.display = "block";
    }
    
    else 
    {
         atype.style.display = "none";
        
        }
});


</script>

</head>

<body>


<form>
        
        <div>
        <input name="check_type" id="check_type" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $type; ?>">
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Account Type</label>
        <select type="text" name="atype" id="atype" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $atype; ?>">
        <option value="<?php echo $atype; ?>" selected><?php echo $atype; ?></option>
                  <option value="User">User</option>
                  <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                  
                </select>
        
        <span></span>
        </div>
        <div>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </div>

</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: depending on what type of element `check_type` is then you might be missing `.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the value of **check_type**. But it depends on what types of the element you are using for check_type. If its input type then **value** otherwise **innerHTML**

**UPDATED**

Type: Admin

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Input Type
    var check_type = document.getElementById("check_type");
    var textfield1 = document.getElementById("atype");

    if(check_type.value == 'Admin') {
        textfield1.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      textfield1.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div>
    <input name="check_type" id="check_type" type="hidden" value="Admin">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Account Type</label>
    <select type="text" name="atype" id="atype" class="form-control">
      <option value="User">User</option>
      <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Type: User

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Input Type
    var check_type = document.getElementById("check_type");
    var textfield1 = document.getElementById("atype");

    if(check_type.value == 'Admin') {
        textfield1.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      textfield1.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div>
    <input name="check_type" id="check_type" type="hidden" value="User">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Account Type</label>
    <select type="text" name="atype" id="atype" class="form-control">
      <option value="User">User</option>
      <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried the code; I changed the value in the check_type field; but, it did not hide the text field.

Comment: Please add your HTML? then we can understand what's happening. And also check for any error in the developer console. It might also the case of your javascript breaking.

Comment: I uploaded the html code as well, please check.

Comment: I updated the code that copied from yours. It's working. BTW do you want to dynamically change the show/hide functionality?

Comment: it is still not working. Please test it by changing the value of the check_type input field to User. You will see, it does not hide the text field.

Comment: @JackYuan I added both. Try to run the snipets.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out what was wrong. it worked when I placed the jquery script link above the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Just add value in your get element to get the element value try :

> check_type.value

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var check_type = document.getElementById("check_type");
    var textfield1 = document.getElementById("textfield1");

    if(check_type.value == 'Admin')
    {
        textfield1.style.display = "block";
    }
    
    else 
    {
         textfield1.style.display = "none";
        
        }
});


</script>
```